# Binary dividing with a remainder

Tags: binary

How much is $\frac{101000}{1001}$ in binary?
I checked in 3 sites, each displayed another result.

The result I get is 100 with a reminder of 100.
Can you please try and solve it and show how you did?

Comment: You can verify that your answer is correct by converting to decimal and checking: you are computing 40/9 = 4 + 4/9.

Comment: @AustinA. Thank you! You can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check your answer by converting to decimal and back: 101000b = 40d divided by 1001b = 9d equals 4d with remainder 4d. Converting the answer back to binary gives quotient 100b with remainder 100b. Your answer is correct.